# Salesforce1 Lisview

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, salesforce1-app

How can i get a lisview in the Salesforce1 App like this?
Maybe, i think the new button is a kind of flexipage tag?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your listviews are already available out of the box when you add the "smart search items" in the mobile navigation. (This section in the menu will be called Recent Items)
In the Salesforce1 menu you then open the object for which you want to see the listviews.

You will not see all available listviews there but only 4.
If you need to see the other listviews, you can search for them on the name of the listview like you would search on any other object.

The screenshot that you added in your question is exactly what the smart search items do. If that doesn't suit your needs, have a look at how to build flexipages. But first have a play with how the smart search items work.

Another tip: you control the order in which the objects appear under the smart search items by doing a search in normal salesforce. Then hover over the objects on the left and a pin icon will appear. Do note that this pinning is specific to each user so you will have to train your users to use it correctly. It gives the flexibility though that your users can decide for themselves which objects they want to see.